# Do vinegar or salt prevent the cloth colors from bleeding?

Tags: consumer-products, natural-remedies, cleaning

Here are the claims:

> Vinegar helps “set” colors and prevents build-up of detergent residue, which contributes to color fading. [...] Pour ½ cup of salt in the wash cycle to prevent the dyes in colored fabrics from bleeding.

[4 Natural Ways to Keep Colors Bright](http://www.organicauthority.com/sanctuary/4-natural-ways-to-keep-colors-bright-clothes-laundry.html)

> Add a tablespoon of salt to the wash, and the chloride will help our clothing pack a colorful punch when it comes out of the dryer. The reason? Chloride found in salt actually helps to seal the color in fabrics, thus keeping it from fading. [...] If you add ½ cup of white vinegar to the rinse cycle, the liquid will freshen up your laundry and help colors maintain their intensity.

[The Natural Way to Keep Fabric from Fading](http://www.craftsy.com/blog/2014/03/how-to-keep-fabric-from-fading/)

Is there any evidence to support the claims?

Comment: I doubt it. Many of these tips date from fifty years ago or more. Even if they had some utility back then, modern dyes are more resilient.

Comment: Anecdotally, I had some red cloth that I was trying to make colour fast. Washing repeatedly with salt and with vinegar had no appreciable effect, and is another reason I am a vinegar cynic.

Comment: As an aside - I use both a salt water soak and added vinegar to wash to try and santiize/de-funk/de-stink laundry, especially workout clothes.  It seems to have a certain amount of positive effect that just detergent does not.

Answer (score 5):

Salt has been used as a mordant (dye-fixer) for ages. Packs of RIT brand dye suggest adding salt (or vinegar, for synthetics) to the dye bath to help the color set.

https://www.ritdye.com/techniques/the-basics/stovetop-technique/

OTOH, they are also using the hottest water possible, which is hard on clothes, so not for frequent use. Note also that this is for *when you are dying cloth* and may not be any help when *washing* same.

But there is at least a grain (sorry) of truth to the idea.

Comment: FYI - Usually when helping a dye set, the fabric's pH and chemistry is altered so the dye can chemically bond with the fabric. Once that bonding/setting is done, a normal wash restores normal pH and the fabric is not susceptible to taking on additional, unwanted dyes. Creating a better environment for accepting dye, initially, is really unrelated to whether that dye is retained, as you correctly surmised.